# Custom filter with scipy ndimage

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

Is there a way to define a custom filter for image processing in Scipy? I need a filter that, given a structural element located at pixel i,j, it assigns a value of that pixel to all other pixels covered by that structural element.

**Edit**: A filter would be similar to a morphology filter, like erosion/dilation, but instead of assigning a minimum/maximum value over a structural element to a pixel, I want to assign a pixel's value to all other pixels in its neighborhood.

Comment: Custom filter in what aspect? Convolution/Correlation? Morphology?  You say "structural element" so it could be morphology.  Please be more specific and if possible, attach a visual / numerical example of what it is you're after.

Comment: How do you deal with the case of overlapping neighbourhoods?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using **convolution**:

```
from scipy import ndimage
img = np.array([[1, 2, 0, 0], [5, 3, 0, 4], [0, 0, 0, 7], [9, 3, 0, 0]])
f = np.array([[1,1,1],[1,1,0],[1,0,0]])
result = ndimage.convolve(img, f)
```

You can find more about that [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.convolve.html).